# How do I interact with a blocking queue in a RESTful service in Java?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

Here's what I am trying to do:

In a server-client system, the client sends some POST requests at a particular endpoint. The server(RestService) takes the request and puts it in an unbounded blocking queue. Another service in the server should check the queue and process each request from the client synchronously.

I am able to add the request in a LinkedBlocking queue. How do I implement a background service or function which keeps checking the queue and executes it synchronously?

Comment: I found this article [Java: BlockingQueues and Continuous Monitoring](https://dzone.com/articles/java-blocking-queue-continuous-monitoring) helpful

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to put the requests in a queue? Did you consider using [AsyncResponse](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/AsyncResponse.html) to handle the requests asynchronously on the server-side?

Comment: I want the server to process the requests synchronously, so I believe a queue especially a BlockingQueue could be used here